# Is there any approach to preserve variable info inspected while debugging in VS Code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'd not like to frequently perform debug when I focus on programming. So is there any approach to preserve variable info in VS Code without having to perform debug again on both web-side and node-side. variable info may display as below:
[image]

Comment: You can log the data and keep the log?

Comment: @VLAZ  I'd like to know is there available VS code plugin to work around it.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable about VS plugins, so I can't say.